# How do you print fixed width strings with radare's print format `pf`?

Tags: radare2, strings

Let's say I have a byte sequence where `U` is an unsigned int (4 bytes), and `ccccccccccccccc` is a 15 byte character array

```
UcccccccccccccccU
```

Is it possible to print this structure using `pf`? I can print this with

```
pf i;
ps 15 @ 4;
pf i @ 19;
```

If both of those integers were next to each other, I could do `pf ii`, and what I would like to do is something like `pf is15i` -- which doesn't work because `s` is for `* char[]` to a string, and not a char array.

If I do something like `pf 5c`, I get them outputted as single characters (ex.,)

```
0x00000008 [0] {
  0x00000008 = '6'
}
0x00000009 [1] {
  0x00000009 = '0'
}
0x0000000a [2] {
  0x0000000a = '0'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand how to use `pf` the way you want, we should go over it step-by-step.

I opened an empty memory for a radare2 playground:

```
$ r2 malloc://200
[0x00000000]>
```

Next, I wrote date to this playground, inspired by your example:

```
[0x00000000]> wx AABBCCDD @ 0
[0x00000000]> w ccccccccccccccc @ 4
[0x00000000]> wx 11223344 @ 19
```

Basically, I wrote 4 bytes, followed by 15 characters and then other 4 bytes. This is how it looks in the memory:

```
[0x00000000]> px 32
- offset -   0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F  0123456789ABCDEF
0x00000000  aabb ccdd 6363 6363 6363 6363 6363 6363  ....cccccccccccc
0x00000010  6363 6311 2233 4400 0000 0000 0000 0000  ccc."3D.........
```

To print this structure I did something like this:

```
[0x00000000]> pf x[15]zx
0x00000000 = 0xddccbbaa
0x00000004 = ccccccccccccccc
0x00000013 = 0x44332211
```

As you already know, `pf` is used to print formatted data. By using `pf??` and `pf???` you can see examples and understand each part of my command.

You can use `i` instead of `x` if you want to print integers.

```
[0x00000000]> pf i[15]zi 1st 2nd third
   1st : 0x00000000 = -573785174
   2nd : 0x00000004 = ccccccccccccccc
 third : 0x00000013 = 1144201745
```

My structure consists of 4 parts:

- `pf` command
- `x` where `x` is being used to print hex value (of 4 bytes)
- `[15]z` to print 15 characters of a string
- `x` to print another hex value

You can also name the fields:

```
[0x00000000]> pf x[15]zx 1st 2nd third
   1st : 0x00000000 = 0xddccbbaa
   2nd : 0x00000004 = ccccccccccccccc
 third : 0x00000013 = 0x44332211
```

You can use other format characters such as `e` to swap endians, etc

Comment: I understand most of that, but where did you `[15]z` from the syntax? I tried `c15` as a syntax which seemed more intuitive. Also what will yours do if the 15-characters is `\0\0foo\0\bar`, ie not a c-string?

Comment: Lol it's documented like this `pf: pf[.k[.f[=v]]|[v]]|[n]|[0|cnt][fmt] [a0 a1 ...]` That's the `[0|cnt]` with the mandatory `[]` ....well that's totally user-friendly.

Comment: It is documented at `pf???`. And for your foo-bar example -- assume we have the following bytes in memory: `aabbccdd0000666f6f0062617200eeff1122`, You can print it with: `pf x..zzx` and you'll get 4 fields: 4 bytes hex, "foo", "bar" and another 4 bytes hex.

Comment: Yep, all this checks out and works -- though I have to wonder why for `z` the length `[15]z` and for `N`, it's `N1`